# Irreducible polynomials in fields & factor rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $I=f(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})[x]$ where $f=x^3+x+[1]$. How many elements are in the field $(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})[x]/I$?

Express $Y=[4]X^3+X+[3]$ in the form $Y=aX^2+bX+c$ where $X=x+I$ where $Y\in(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})[x]$ and $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$.

For the very first part I believe there are $5^3=125$ elements - in a past assignment I saw a similar question with $5$ replaced with $2$ and there were $8$ elements, and when replaced with $3$ there were $27$. But I'm not quite sure how to justify this and would like help to show that in the general case there are $n^3$ such elements. I can't see how this would follow naturally though?

For the second part I have no idea where to even start.

Comment: What polynomial is $f$?

Comment: @DouglasMolin edited

Comment: It is a very general fact of algebra that if $K$ is any field and $p \in K[X]$ a polynomial, then the quotient ring $K[X] /(p)$ has $K$-dimension $=\deg(p)$. (Totally regardless of whether $p$ is reducible or not.) In your case, $3$. A three-dimensional vector space over the field with $5$ elements has ... elements.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part: When $f\in \mathbb{F}_p[X]$ is a cubic polynomial,  there are three possibilites:

1. $f$ is irreducible, in which case the ideal $(f)$ is maximal and so $\mathbb{F}_p[X]/(f)\simeq \mathbb{F}_{p^3}.$
2. $f$ has two irreducible factors (linear and quadratic), i.e. $(f)=(l)\cap(q)$ and so $\mathbb{F}_{p}[X]/(f)\simeq \mathbb{F}_{p}[X]/(l)\times\mathbb{F}_{p}[X]/(q)\simeq \mathbb{F}_{p}\times\mathbb{F}_{p^2}.$
3. $f$ has three linear factors, i.e. $(f)=(l_1)\cap(l_2)\cap(l_3)$ and so $\mathbb{F}_{p}[X]/(f) \simeq \mathbb{F}_{p}\times\mathbb{F}_{p}\times\mathbb{F}_{p}$

To see which of the above 3 cases you are in, you should see if the polynomial has any roots in $\mathbb{F}_5$.

For the second part: note that in $\mathbb{F}_5[X]/(f),$ you have the equality $$x^3=-x-1$$
(here $x$ denotes the equivalence class/coset $X+I$). Use that to rewrite $Y$!

Comment: I'm quite confused - why must $x^3+x+1=0$? Surely we have only that it is $0,1,2,3$ or $4$? Also, if we have $x^3=-x-1$ how do we write $Y$ in terms of $X$ (as opposed to $x$)?

Comment: The $x$ in $x^3+x+1=0$ is the coset $X+I$, not an element of $\mathbb{F}_5$. Since $X^3+X+1=f$ you have $x^3+x+1=0$ in $\mathbb{F}_5[X]/(f)$.

Comment: So we can say that as $x^3=-x-1$ we have $[4]x^3+x+1=4(-x-1)+x+1=-[3]x-[3]=[2]x+[2]$. As such we have $Y=[2]X+[2]$?

Comment: Yes, that looks correct to me.